# How to fix Veracode CWE 117 for HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, veracode

I am getting [Veracode CWE 117](https://www.veracode.com/security/java/cwe-117) ("Improper Output Sanitization for Logs") for HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name when executing the following code in a C# 4.0/ASP.Net web application.

```cs
var user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last();
var message = $" User '{user}' logged in.";
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Log(LogLevel.Info, message);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: There's discussion on the Veracode forums (easily findable by a search engine) that discuss [how to remediate this](https://community.veracode.com/s/question/0D52T00004sTKg1SAG/how-to-fix-cwe-117-improper-output-neutralization-for-logs-in-net-core-22-solution).

Comment: Specifically, the recommendation is to use one of the supported [cleansing functions](https://help.veracode.com/r/review_cleansers) on your `message` before attempting to log it.